# What is dispatcherIndex used for in React TODO example

Tags: reactjs, flux

All,

I just start learning React FLUX with Facebook TODO example  [Here](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html)

There is a field in TODO Store called dispatcherIndex, I wonder what that field used for?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `dispatcherIndex` is never invoked as you normally would expect from a function, i.e., `TodoStore.dispatcherIndex()`.

But since the value of `dispatcherIndex` is a function call (no just a function, but a **function call**), that function call happens in the initialization of your object. So when the `TodoStore` is initialized, this code (the function call) is run:

```
AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
  var action = payload.action;
  var text;

  switch(action.actionType) {
    case TodoConstants.TODO_CREATE:
      text = action.text.trim();
      if (text !== '') {
        create(text);
        TodoStore.emitChange();
      }
      break;

    case TodoConstants.TODO_DESTROY:
      destroy(action.id);
      TodoStore.emitChange();
      break;
  // add more cases for other actionTypes, like TODO_UPDATE, etc.
  }
  return true; // No errors. Needed by promise in Dispatcher.
})
```

You're calling `AppDispatcher.register` and passing it a callback function. This callback you are passing is not executed now, it is registered (added to the `_callbacks` array) to be called later, whenever you call one of the methods that calls `AppDispatcher.handleViewAction`, that are `TodoActions.create` and `TodoActions.destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet in that page, they have included the tying up of the Dispatcher to the Store within the Store definition and that is what the dispatcherIndex is doing.

However, in the [code that has been put on github](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/stores/TodoStore.js), this is outside the store definition. In that code, Store definition starts at line 77

```
var TodoStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
```

and ends at line 117 after which you are registering the callback

```
    removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }
}); //Todo Store definition ends here

// Register callback to handle all updates
AppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
  var text;

  switch(action.actionType) {
    case TodoConstants.TODO_CREATE:
      text = action.text.trim();
      if (text !== '') {
        create(text);
        TodoStore.emitChange();
      }
      break;
```

Basically, in Flux architecture, flow is unidirectional, so from the React components action is triggered and this action is then *dispatched* to those stores where the callback has been registered for that action.

[image: Flux Architecture]

Comment: Thanks, I guess I too new to React to understand what you mean, could you brief mention where and how does that dispatcherIndex get used? OR: Does that mean the dispatcherIndex  itself has little use but the initialization process of it is important?

Comment: I have the same doubt. There is a definition of `dispatcherIndex`, but this method is referenced nowhere else in the project. Though it gets called when every action occurs. This answer is broad about the Flux architecture but doesn't answer the OP doubt, as noted in the comment above.